# SQL Function lookup like - slow performance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have Table categories(categoryId int, keyword nvarchar(180)), it has about 3000 rows.
I need to lookup the categoryId for table messages(messageId int, message nvarchar(512), categoryId int, ...) table increase 10 Million/Day.

I wrote this a function that return categoryId:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetCategoryId](@message nvarchar(512)) 
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN 
    declare @categoryId int; 
    select top 1 @categoryId  =CategoryId from category c   
        WHERE   @message like '%' + keyword + '%'     
        order by len(keyword) desc  
    RETURN @categoryId
END
```

I run this query:

```
update [messages] set categoryId = [dbo].[GetCategoryId]([message]) 
    where messageId > @LastUpdatedMessageId
```

the performance is very slow comparing to the number of records per day, it took about 5 hours to categorize my data

Comment: (1) You have written a query, not a function.  (2) Using wildcards with `like` is not good for performance.  (3) Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic would all help.

Comment: I edited my question, please check

Comment: . . Functions are slow.  A `join` would be faster, but it will still be quite slow.

Comment: if you get 10 million new messages a day and compare each one against 3000 strings that is going to be 30 billion string comparisons. you could look at CLR and regex to speed things up

Comment: The reason this will be slow is that 1) the entire table will be scanned each invocation (because of the leading wildcard search criteria) and 2) all matching results will be ordered in order to select the one with the longest value.

Comment: this is exactly what is happening in SQL, 30 billion operation/day  and wildcard search criteria. I'm looking for a solution

Comment: I'm thinking to use C# windows service that will have the keywords in memory and lookup the categoryId for batches of 10000 message, do you think that this will be faste.  I give up to find a solution on SQL

Comment: Firstly, use an inlineable table-valued function instead of a imperative, scalar-valued function. This can often increase performance manyfold. But I think the more fundamental problem is the use of fuzzy matching - with 10m records a day and 3,000 potential keywords to be matched, you need to find a way of decomposing the messages into indexable keywords - for example, if the message is an English sentence, then splitting at every space and then looking up each word could be far more performant.

Comment: we the message is nvarchar and it could be in any language

Comment: @DevL I think you're missing something. could you please provide an existing sample (if not sensitive), with both tables schema. And who insert the `messages` is it a user or a server ?.

Comment: @iSR5 a service application insert the messages

Comment: @DevL If possible, you can adjust the service application to process it instead because you'll get more search capabilities outside SQL Server, and much faster performance. In such a case, I would suggest to review the schema, and usual data (e.g. keywords, messages), and see what you can do to to fill in the gaps (like saving common keywords, searches ..etc.) to get faster results and also reduce the IO consumption.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do these:

1- create procedure 
2- in your procedure make join your category table with messages
3- make index on category_id //(I am not sure for this but I think it will be good)

```
SELECT top (1) categoryId
FROM category c   
JOIN Messages M      ON C.KEYWORD = M.Message
```

OR

```
SELECT top (1) categoryId
FROM category c   
JOIN Messages M      ON C.KEYWORD LIKE M.Message
```

but I suggest first query beacuse it has better performance

I hope it help you